# Is the word "overweight" used incorrectly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

On the following [website](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-statistics/overweight-obesity) I came across the title **Prevalence of Overweight and Obesity**.

That doesn't sound quite right to me.

> Obesity is the state of being obese, but how can **overweight** be the
>   state of being overweight?

Nevertheless, I've come across this use of the word **overweight** in scientific literature as well.

Shouldn't the sentence be phrased **Prevalence of Overweightness and Obesity**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a fascinating question, because at first it appears you are right. Something along the lines of "Prevalence of Overweightness and Obesity" would be correct. However, checking the dictionary, "overweight" can be a noun meaning "weight in excess". All that "overweightness" would be doing is changing an adjective to a noun, and that's apparently not required. Thus, "Prevalence of Overweight and Obesity" is acceptable usage.

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago I was also amazed to discover that **overweight** is used as a noun - especially in scientific and medical literature. I've composed a poem, "The Battle with Overweight", haha

> Fridgeward he pressed, his famishment to sate,
>   But soon drew back, afraid of Overweight.
>   O, Overweight! How many gallant gluttons
>   For fear of you forbear their spicy muttons.